# Honeypot technique for php form

Tags: php, wordpress, spam, honeypot

I'm trying use honeypot technique for my custom form on wordpress site. 
My form look like that.

```
<form id="form-1" 
    action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/mail.php" method="post" class="order__form form">
    <p class="form__title">Order and Receive 30% off</p>
    <p class="form__text">fill out this form so you can get sale</p>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form__item" placeholder="Your name">
    <input type="email" name="email" required class="form__item" placeholder="Email address">
    <p class="robotic" id="pot">
        <label>If you're human leave this blank:</label>
        <input name="robotest" type="text" id="robotest" class="robotest" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="button form__button">
</form>
```

Input with name `robotest` for validation on server side.

This is `mail.php` code:

```
<?php
    $mess = '';
    $mess .= '<hr>';
    if($_POST['robotest'] != ''){
        $error = "You are a gutless robot.";
    } else {
        if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
            $name = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name'])), 0, 100);
            $mess .= '<b>Имя отправителя: </b>' . $name . '<br>';
        }
        if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
            if($_POST['email']!=''){
                $email = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email'])), 0, 100);
                $mess .= '<b>E-mail: </b>' . $email . '<br>';
            }
        }
    }

    $mess .= '<b>Заявка пришла со страницы:</b> ' . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] .'<br>'; 
    $mess .= '<hr>';

    require 'class.phpmailer.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->AddAddress('xxx2xxx.com','');
    $mail->IsHTML(true); 
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8"; 
    $mail->Subject = "new";
    $mail->From = "new"; 
    $mail->FromName = "new"; 
    $mail->Body = $mess;

    if ($mail->Send()) {
        header('Location: ../'); 
    } else { 
        die ('Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo); 
    }

    header("Location: /thanks/");

?>
```

When I add validation for `robotest`, this script doesn't work.

Comment: `this script doesn't work` HOW? Blank page? No letter? Pc explodes?

Comment: It's working, but not validate. The main idea that when bot fill the robotest field script must be show error. But now it's every time submit and i recieve email.

Comment: Because you logic is flawed. And if you indent you code properly - you will see it.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `$error` variable but you are not using it anywhere.

If you change the:

```
$error = "You are a gutless robot.";
```

To a:

```
die( "You are a gutless robot." );
```

You will have what you describe you want to have.